# How to transform an image with illumination to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to binary a photo but there are lighting problems, making it difficult to read the license plate later.

Some of code:

```
def Lp_filter_2(LpImg,erosion_k):
    if (len(LpImg)): #check if there is at least one license image
        # Scales, calculates absolute values, and converts the result to 8-bit.
        plate_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(LpImg[0], alpha=(255.0))
        plate_image = LpImg #image_cropped

        # convert to grayscale and blur the image
        grayy = cv2.cvtColor(plate_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayy,(3,3),0) #3,3

        binary = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] #180,255 ??
        
    # visualize results    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
    plt.rcParams.update({"font.size":18})
    grid = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2,nrows=3,figure = fig)
    plot_image = [plate_image, grayy, blur, binary]
    plot_name = ["plate_image","gray","blur", "binary"]

    return plot_image[0],plot_image[1],plot_image[2],plot_image[3]
```

Call it with:

```
LpImg= cv2.imread('License_plate.jpg')
filter = Lp_filter_2(LpImg,4)

cv2_imshow(filter[0])
cv2_imshow(filter[1])
cv2_imshow(filter[2])
cv2_imshow(filter[3])
```

With this result:

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Also I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124552/trying-to-segment-characters-using-opencv-ilumination-problem?noredirect=1#comment109875329_62124552) but with no success.

Any ideas to have the binary image with no problems with lighting? or reduce it

Comment: Otsu cannot work for an image like that. You're eating soup with a fork... How can you expect any useful output if you apply tools you don't know?

Comment: its 2020, use deeplearning like things for ocr or detection task

Comment: I'm using a cnn to extract license plate, then this part which its manual (segment characters), and finally character recognition using another cnn. If you have a github or tutorial to segment characters it would be awesome

Comment: @Piglet any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: that would depend on how other images look like but as flankechen mentioned I also see no reason to not use machine learning.